# Cfexecute 7zip write to log file

Tags: command-line, coldfusion-9, 7zip

I am executing 7zip via cfexecute. I have tested the command in the command prompt on the cf box. In command prompt I put:

```
C:\apps\7-Zip\7z.exe e \\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\distapps\20160810_GTECHREC_000085597_001.zip  -o\\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\distapps\unzip -bsp1 > \\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\distapps\unzip\log.txt
```

This unzips the files correctly and writes log.txt to the same folder.

I can get the unzip to happen correctly using cfexecute, but when I add the line for writing the log file, nothing happens (neither the unzip or the log). I have tried:

```
<cfexecute name="C:\apps\7-Zip\7z.exe" arguments="e \\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\distapps\20160810_GTECHREC_000085597_001.zip  -o\\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\distapps\unzip -bsp1 > \\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\distapps\unzip\log.txt">
```

```
<cfexecute name="C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" arguments="C:\apps\7-Zip\7z.exe e \\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\distapps\20160810_GTECHREC_000085597_001.zip  -o\\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\distapps\unzip -bsp1 > \\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\distapps\unzip\log.txt">
```

And many other variations of the above. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `>`  to generate the log file, can you try setting the `outputFile` argument?

Answer (score 0):

the outputfile argument seems to be adding  "-bso1 > c:\whereever\mylogfile.txt" to the end of your command

I also had failed to do the -bso1 and it still worked in some places but it still worked in some scenerios until I started adding filters